# Rendering Django Template Blocks in Specific Places on Page

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-oscar

I am trying to achieve something in Django Templating Language without knowing whether it is possible (without resorting to JS or something like that).

I have the following code (from Django-Oscar) which renders 3 blocks of promotions on the main page:

```
{# Render promotions #}
<div id="promotions">
    {% for promotion in promotions_page %}
       {% render_promotion promotion %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

These three blocks are Single Item, Products and New Arrivals. The code above appears in the `layout.html` which is essentially responsible for rendering the entire layout of the main page.

The problem is that as soon as soon as Django encounters this code, it renders all of the promotions there one after another. I, however, would like to chose where on the page I place them. What's more, I do not believe that I have much flexibility in how I render them, read - I do not want to change the Oscar e-commerce and rendering code unless absolutely necessary.

Since I have access to individual templates for Single Item, Products and New Arrivals promotions, I tried creating DTL blocks there and then calling those blocks at proper places on the `layout.html`. However, that does not work.

What is a proper and most efficient way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Django templating system provides features that let you add your custom templates in place of the ones that come with the apps. You don't need to patch django-oscar for this.

Start here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/howto/overriding-templates/

Hope I added enlightenment.